One single physical drive with one partition. Somehow unintentionally became dynamic and split. How could this have happened?
Simple question that has got me puzzled.
Windows 10 installation ~5 years old. D: HDD was freshly formatted and used since the beginning, with classic data stuff.
In the last months I noticed strange cut/copy behavior.
The explorer copy progress went to 100% with the appropriate speed, but it never finished.
The copy window stayed open for minutes at 100%, then finished and closed.
I checked SMART, everything ok. A quick look in the Disk Management revealed that somehow:
The single 1TB HDD got converted to dynamic, split in two dynamic partitions and then got "mounted" as one single D: partition.
How did this happen ?
I neither recall making the drive dynamic, nor entering the strange 195+736GB ratio.
Notes:
The logon process started to take about 25 seconds to complete, when booting up.
(User-xyz authenticated, then "Welcome O" with the spinning-dot animation)
I know that it won't be mergeable or anything like that. The only solution will be to copy the entire data to another drive, format as basic and copy the data back.
The strange IO behavior still shouldn't be caused by this, right ?
I just cut and pasted about 80 files totaling 200MB (photos)...
Can anyone explain, what happened ? Or have you encountered something similar ?
Disk Management
Task Manager

I've worked with dynamic disks before and they should not cause this much slow down. As for what it created, dunno, but might not worth the time and there may be a different underlying problem.

Everything you describe suggests the disk is failing. Without providing the S.M.A.R.T information I wouldn’t rule out the possibility that the drive is indeed failing
